# OpenGL texture mapping bug

Tags: c#, opengl

Have a little bug. I'm making the texture and map it to the Quad this way... Seems all right. But if I set "Z" to -5.0f or less, it becomes not showed. Have any thoughts?

```
gl.Begin( BeginMode.Quads );
gl.TexCoord( 0.0f, 1.0f ); gl.Vertex( 0, 0, Z );
gl.TexCoord( 1.0f, 1.0f ); gl.Vertex(width, 0, Z);
gl.TexCoord( 1.0f, 0.0f ); gl.Vertex(width, height, Z);
gl.TexCoord( 0.0f, 0.0f ); gl.Vertex(0, height, Z);
gl.End();
```

Comment: Double check your clipping region (http://i.stack.imgur.com/h15iq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a shoebox with a rectangle shaped hole at the long end. Looking through the hole you can see what is inside the box. The hole is your viewport, and the inside of the box is your scene. The third parameter of gl.Vertex() is the perpendicular distance to the viewport.

So 1 places the quad exactly 1 unit "into" the box (your scene), -1 does the same but the other direction. So using a negative number there places the quad outside the box, while the user is looking into the box. The quad is basically behind your camera so to speak. Try inserting a positive number for Z and see what happens to the quad.

As Datenwolf correctly noted, using the default viewport configuration, lower than 0 means further into the scene, while higher than 0 means your object will end up behind the camera.

Comment: OpenGL uses a right handed coordinate system by default and in fact you're looking down the negative Z axis if you're not moving the view transformation.

Comment: @datenwolf That is correct, but the OP didn't specify that he uses the default coordinate system. With the given information, this is the closest to an answer one can get. I will add that with default settings my example is reversed.

Comment: That's only true if you apply a projection matrix. In NDC space, smaller values are closer to the viewer. OpenGL's default coordinate system (NDC) is left handed.